# Tkinter: How do I make it so that the hyperlinks have center alignments in the text widget?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am making a recommendation app in Tkinter where a user will input a movie/tv show and it will show 10 similar items with it's IMDb link. See Picture: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ucFXX.jpg

The problem is I can't get the hyperlinks to center align, despite being able to make standalone text to center align. Here's the code:

```
from tkinter import *
from recommendation_system import imdb_recommendation_system as ims
from tkHyperlinkManager import *
from functools import partial
import webbrowser
import re


def open_link(my_url):
    webbrowser.open_new(url=my_url)


def get_text(event=None):
    """

    :param event: None
    :return: None

    Gets the recommendations and shows it in a text widget.
    """

    text_widget = Text(frame, font='Arial 12 italic', cursor='arrow', bg='#A9A9A9', height=10, width=50)
    hyperlink = HyperlinkManager(text_widget)
    text_widget.tag_configure('tag-center', justify='center')
    query = entry1.get()
    query = ' '.join([word for word in re.split(r'\s+', query) if word != ''])  # handling white space
    text = ims.get_recommendations(query) # returns a list or dataframe

    if isinstance(text, list):  # if the movie/tv show not found, prints 'TV Show/Movie not found!'
        text = '\n'.join(text)
        text_widget.insert(1.0, text, 'tag-center')

    else:  # if found iterate over the dataframe to create hyperlinks in the text widget
        text_widget.delete(1.0, END)
        for _, title, imdb_url in text.itertuples():
            text_widget.insert(END, title, hyperlink.add(partial(open_link, imdb_url)))
            text_widget.insert(END, '\n')

    text_widget.place(x=173, y=310)
    text_widget.configure(state='disabled')
```

I tried this:

```
text_widget.insert(END, title, hyperlink.add(partial(open_link, imdb_url)), 'tag-center')
```

but didn't get the desired output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution:

Had to set `justify='center'` in `self.text.tag_config` attribute in `tkHyperlinkManager.py`.